# JavaScript Change elements in line and print them in different lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I have this code to find the matching names and change them to others.
But they change every time and in the same line.

```
var names1 = ["Rui", "Jose", "Carlos", "Miguel"];

var names2 = ["Rui", "Tiago", "Jose", "Carlos", "Rogerio"];

for (var i = 0; i < names1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < names2.length; j++) {

    if (names1[i] == names2[j]) {

      names2[j] = "Maria", "Fred";

    }

  }
}

console.log(names2);
```

I want to know how to print them in different lines.
Because it shows like this:

MariaFred

Tiago

MariaFred

MariaFred

Rogerio

And I wanted:

maria,

Fred,

Tiago,

Rogerio.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is expected result of `names2[j] = "Maria", "Fred";`?

Comment: Is names2[j] = "Maria", "Fred"; a typo? Should it be names2[j] = "Maria" + "Fred";

Comment: so what i wanted is to show like this:

Comment: maria,

Fred,

Tiago,

Rogerio.

Comment: but it shows like this

Comment: MariaFred

Tiago

MariaFred

MariaFred

Rogerio

Comment: Thank you Santaaa !

Comment: So what's wrong with Miguel..?

Comment: nothing i just forgot to add it

Comment: what is expected when names match ? can you clarify a little more ?

Comment: i need the final print ot look like this 'Maria', 'Tiago', 'Fred',  'Rogerio'

Comment: From my understanding you need 

(name1 intersection name2 ) 

am i correct ?

Comment: so the names that match i want them to be deleted and switched for other random names in this case maria and fred

Comment: any random name is ambiguous, is that any name will be generated on the fly ?

Comment: this answer from nina scholz is almost there but print the name maria more than once

Comment: no i choose the names

Comment: I have tried an example https://repl.it/Ew26 i think the random names should be chosen from some source

Comment: Yes you are right thx

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array for the excahnge names and an index for inserting a changed name if a matched name is found.

```js
var names1 = ["Rui", "Jose", "Carlos", "Miguel"],
    names2 = ["Rui", "Tiago", "Jose", "Carlos", "Rogerio"],
    matched = ["Maria", "Fred"],
    index = 0,
    i, j;

outer: for (j = 0; j < names2.length; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < names1.length; i++) {
        if (names1[i] == names2[j]) {
            names2[j] = matched[index++];
            index %= matched.length;
            continue outer;
        }
    }
}

console.log(names2);
```

To speed up the check, you could use a hash table and check against it.

```js
var names1 = ["Rui", "Jose", "Carlos", "Miguel"],
    names2 = ["Rui", "Tiago", "Jose", "Carlos", "Rogerio"],
    matched = ["Maria", "Fred"],
    index = 0,
    hash = Object.create(null);

names1.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a] = true;
});

names2.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (hash[a]) {
        aa[i] = matched[index++];
        index %= matched.length;
    }
});

console.log(names2);
```

Comment: it work pretty well but in the second match prints maria again, any way to change that?? i am getting this : 'Maria', 'Tiago', 'Fred', 'Maria', 'Rogerio'

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
console.log(names2)
```

try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < names2.length; i++) {
console.log(names2[i]);
```

}

Comment: not rly it prints maria multiple times and doesn print Fred.

Comment: because it printes maria the amount of times the element match and doesn print the second name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var names1 = ["Rui", "Jose", "Carlos", "Miguel"];
var names2 = ["Rui", "Tiago", "Jose", "Carlos", "Rogerio"];
var matchFound = false;
for (var i = 0; i < names1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < names2.length; j++) {
    if (names1[i] == names2[j] && matchFound === false) {
      // when the name matches, print Maria and Fred in 2 different lines
      console.log("Maria,");
      console.log("Fred,");
      matchFound  = true;
    } else { // if name doesn't match, just print the element from 2nd array
       console.log(names2[j]");
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IN the following example, I think the random names should be chosen from some source

```
var names1 = ["Rui", "Jose", "Carlos", "Miguel"];
var names2 = ["Rui", "Tiago", "Jose", "Carlos", "Rogerio"];
var random_names = ['Maria', 'Fred', 'Someother']
var random_names_counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < names1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < names2.length; j++) {
        if (names1[i] == names2[j]) {
            names2[j] = random_names[random_names_counter++];
        }
    }
}

console.log(names2);
```